# Derive short-run demand function?

Tags: economics

Suppose a firm pays £500,000 in short-run costs for its capital and unskilled labour.

Its only
short-run decision, therefore, is to determine how many high-skilled workers, E, to hire.

The
wage for unskilled labour is Ws and the firm's short-run production function is

$Q$ = $f(E)$ = $100E$.

The firm faces a downward sloping demand for its output given by
$Q = 12000 - 20P$, where P is the price per unit at which it sells its product.

Derive the firm's
short-run labour demand function (you can either make E the dependent variable or show the
inverse labour demand curve making Ws the dependent variable). NB; this firm is not a price
taker.

I know that for short-run the following is true: profits = TR - TC = $pf(E)$ - $w_s$$E$

and $pMP_L$ = $w_s$ 
so we have $((12000 - Q) * 100)/20$ = $w_s$ and $Q=100E$

from this $E$ = (60000 - $w_s$)/500

is it right?

Comment: I haven't gone through all the calculations, but in the profit function there's a problem. You said that $w_s$ is the wage for the unskilled workers, but you multiply it by $E$, the number of high-skilled workers. Also you should consider the fixed costs. Take a look again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demand for the product

$r = qp\\
q = 12000 - 20 p\\
r = 12000 p - 20 p^2\\
\frac {dr}{dp} = 12000 - 40 p$

or

$p = 600 - \frac {q}{20}\\
r =  600 q - \frac {q^2}{20}\\
\frac {dr}{dq} = 600 - \frac {q}{10}$

On the costs side

$c = 500,000 + wE\\
E = \frac {q}{100}\\
c = 100,000 + \frac {wq}{100}\\
\frac {dc}{dq} = \frac {w}{100}$

Profits are maximized when marginal revenue equals marginal costs.

$600 - \frac{q}{10} = \frac {w}{100}\\
6000 - \frac {w}{10} = q\\
q = 100e\\
e = 60 - \frac {w}{1000}\\
$

Comment: why in the cost side you are taking 100000 as fixed costs ?

Comment: Sorry 500,000 fixed costs.  It is irrelevant to the final answer though.

Comment: so we do not really need first part of calculations derivative of revenue with respect to price, right?

Comment: so in the final answer w is the wage  of high-skilled workers?

Comment: I didn't use it here.  But, in many cases (and micro economics questions) calculating revenue as a function of price is more common, and what students are accustomed to seeing.